# sql developer export table to xls

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to export the entire query results to xls format without the value truncated (with the header intact).

e.g

[image: truncated value in yellow]

the value is round up to **276408428673510000** when the actual value is suppose to be **276408428673508271**

Using this method

[image]

Comment: The only work around I've found is to use ctrl-a -> ctrl-c-> cahnge the format in excel to text before pasting them in the excel sheet. That's without header. And get the header from the exported excel (with the truncated values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After selecting the data by clicking 'Ctrl+ A' in gride, use 'Ctrl+Shift+C' to copy the data with Header. After pasting the data into MS Excel, try changing the 'format' to number or text. You must be knowing that 'format cells' is available as a right click option in MS Excel.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was use the LPAD or RPAD functions, you give the exact length that you want and when you export the data, these don't round it.